# Initialization of UISwitch causes unrecognized selector exception in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch in my view and everything works fine for iOS 7 both on my device and the simulator, but when I run my application in the iOS 6 simulator I get a weird exception.

The exception breakpoint fires at this particular line of code:

```
self.mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
```

with the following output:

```
-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Is this somehow a bug in the simulator? I have no idea how to fix this and at the moment I don’t have an iOS 6 device at hand.

The relevant stack trace at this point is:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x177e6, 0x0191be52 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
frame #0: 0x0191be52 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
frame #1: 0x01d144bd CoreFoundation`-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 253
frame #2: 0x01c78bbc CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 588
frame #3: 0x01c7894e CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
frame #4: 0x01c0ab10 CoreFoundation`CFArrayGetCount + 80
frame #5: 0x0106cc04 UIKit`__36-[_UISwitchInternalView _labelImage]_block_invoke_0 + 144
frame #6: 0x010a22fe UIKit`+[UIImage(_UIImageTintedInterfaceExtension) _cachedImageForKey:fromBlock:] + 131
frame #7: 0x0106cb6c UIKit`-[_UISwitchInternalView _labelImage] + 187
frame #8: 0x0106e6ed UIKit`-[_UISwitchInternalView _buildControl] + 1454
frame #9: 0x0106b7c1 UIKit`__39-[_UISwitchInternalView initWithFrame:]_block_invoke_0 + 36
frame #10: 0x00eb240c UIKit`+[UIView(Animation) _performWithoutAnimation:] + 82
frame #11: 0x0106b793 UIKit`-[_UISwitchInternalView initWithFrame:] + 420
frame #12: 0x0106f196 UIKit`-[UISwitch _commonInitNewLook] + 225
frame #13: 0x0106f741 UIKit`-[UISwitch initWithFrame:] + 143
frame #14: 0x0106f6ab UIKit`-[UISwitch init] + 118
```

EDIT: I use only two calls regarding UIAppearance and the crash occurs even when I comment them out.

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor slubDarkBlue]];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchBarIcon"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Do you use ARC in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Apple Developer in the Developer Forums got me in the right direction. Turns out it was a localization issue.

I did:

```
[myUserDefaults setObject:inAppLanguage forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

instead of:

```
[myUserDefaults setObject:@[inAppLanguage] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

where inAppLanguage is a NSString like @"de" or @"en". So the UISwitch encountered the single NSString instead of an NSArray of NSStrings.

Answer (score 0):

This does not make a lot of sense, because the crash says something about sending the message "count" to a string. Which points to an issue with a dangling reference. If you are sure that the crash occurs inside `[[UISwitch alloc] init]`, try `[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`

Are you using any appearance methods?

Comment: Exactly. It doesn’t make any sense, but changing to initWithFrame: does the same thing.

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace of the crash.

Comment: Added it to the question.

Comment: Are you using any appearance methods?

Comment: I use them for UITextField and UISearchBar, but nothing for UISwitch or anything else.

Comment: I added the calls I do, but they seem to be irrelevant since the crash occurs even without them.

Comment: Hm.. that does sound weird. Is that a weak property pointer? Did you try to rewrite it to be strong?

Comment: It already is a strong property and I am truly clueless about what to do about it.

Comment: where are you calling that code? is it maybe on a background thread? but then again says thread #1 in the stack trace, so that probably isn't the case.

Comment: I alloc and init a UIViewController I want to display and the UISwitch is a part of that. But it doesn’t matter where I try to init a UISwitch in my project. It fails every time.

Comment: I just tried to alloc a UISwitch in a sample app and added it to the window. It works fine in both iOS6 and iOS7. There must be something fishy going on elsewhere in your code the bug is not in UISwitch.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It’s just in this particular project. I do nothing fancy, forbidden or any weird hacks. That’s why this drives me mad.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you're injecting an `NSString` where there should be an `NSArray` or anything countable here.

In any case it's certainly not a simulator bug, so be sure to double-check your code. It may well be in a previous instruction or initialization. Or even maybe in one of your xib files.

Also, as you don't have the same behavior in iOS 7 and 6, you may want to check for any API change you would have missed.

Comment: I simply try to alloc and init a UISwitch…

Comment: Thanks for the downvote... Hopefully you'll do the opposite when you'll realize that this answer was actually useful. Think about it: why would the native, iOS6 only, simulator only call `count` on a string?

Comment: I certainly would vote if I had enough reputation to vote for anything in the first place.Nonetheless, the exception is somewhere thrown inside the init method even if I create a totally different UISwitch in my ViewController. I don’t see how there can be any API changes involved or how I inject anything at this point.

Comment: Anyway, you need to realize that the error has little to do with you creating a UISwitch. The error clearly says "Someone tried to call `count` on a NSString". See it as you wish, it means that somehow there's an NSString where it shouldn't be.

Comment: True and I figured as much, but I still have no idea how and why this would happen inside an init method (where the exception is thrown from) in which I don’t even have any control.

Comment: Because this `init` may depend on external stuff. Images for example. If you look at your stack, we see that it happens while trying to get an image from an array. Could it be that someone somewhere tries to change the default style of the switches? In any case, what I'm trying to say is that the bug is in your code, not in the simulator. You should keep looking.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. I did set a NSString instead of an NSArray at some point, obviously, at an not so obvious, at least to me, point. Would vote you up, if I could. :)

Comment: Well, as a last resort you could have accepted my answer ;) Well done anyway !